RubixML model always return the same prediction in PHP
I'm trying to extract the product price for different sentences using https://rubixml.com/, but it always returns 260, the first label I give to it
<?php
include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Rubix\ML\Datasets\Labeled;
use Rubix\ML\Datasets\Unlabeled;
use Rubix\ML\Classifiers\KNearestNeighbors;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\WordCountVectorizer;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\TfIdfTransformer;
use Rubix\ML\Pipeline;
use Rubix\ML\Extractors\CSV;

$samples= ['The price is 260','The cost is 500','This shirt costs 300','The value of this item is 450','Sold for 150 dolars'];
$labels = ['260',             '500',            '300',                 '450',                           '150'];

$dataset = new Labeled($samples, $labels);

// genrate the model
$pipeline = new Pipeline([
    new WordCountVectorizer(100),
    new TfIdfTransformer(),
], new KNearestNeighbors(3));

// training with dataset
$pipeline->train($dataset);

// analize new frace
$new = Unlabeled::build([
    ['Price: 1200'],
]);

// Predict
$predictions = $pipeline->predict($new);
var_dump($predictions);

I have changed the values for the KNearestNeighbors, provide larger inputs for train dataset, change the Vectorizer. But nothing changes.

K Nearest Neighbors is a classifier. The classes are the labels that you provided in the training data (this is a fixed list). In your case, they are:

260
500
300
450
150

A prediction will always return one of those classes.
See the documentation and the Iris Flower Classifier example to learn more about KNN.

This does not seem to actually answer the question of why other values in the fixed list are never returned.
